# Problems with matching up PHP strings

Tags: php, transcode

I am making a page that transcodes videoes to different formats. My problem is that I want to skip transcoding mp4 files to mp4. So I have exploded the file extension and that works nicely. I am renaming the files I transcode with an added parameter - the file extension of the original. However when I try to create an if test like under it won't fire.

```
if ($format != "mp4")
{
  transcodeToMp4($file, $format);
}
```

This won't work. So I've been search for alternative ways of solving this:

```
if (strpos($format, "mp4") === FALSE) 
{
  transcodeToMp4($file, $format);
}
```

Anyone have any idea why this won't fire? I get the correct string for the extension in the filename though.

```
$format = strtolower(end(explode(".",$file)));
```

Comment: You're code is working fine on my system (also your first attempt). Are you sure `$format` returns 'mp4'?

Comment: Yes, I am also sending `$format` with the `transcodeToMp4()` and the new names are like mov-123512351235.webm or mp4-123412351235.webm so I know the $format string is correct.

Comment: Are you working in this order: 1. Get `$file` with path, 2. Find `$format`, 3. Check whether `$format == mp4`, if not: 4. Use function `transcodeToMp4()`?

Comment: Yes, as I don't want to transcode mp4 files to mp4. But redreggae helped me solve it. Still weird that the != "mp4" doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `pathinfo` to get the extension:

```
if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) != 'mp4') {
    transcodeToMp4($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function
strstr($format, "mp4")